# understanding set-pnplistitempermission

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp, pnp-powershell

I am trying to use the following cmdlet in the pnp module on O365 and one of the parameters for the cmdlet is `-identity`

```
-Identity The ID of the listitem, or actual ListItem object

Type:   ListItemPipeBind  
Position:   Named  
Accept pipeline input:  True 
Accept wildcard characters: False
```

The parameter says the ID of the listitem **or** the listitem object, I am trying to put the name instead of the ID

So changing `-identity` from

```
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Test' -Identity 1  -User 'Test@test.com' -AddRole 'Contribute' -ClearExisting
```

To

```
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Test' -Identity "TestFolder"  -User 'Test@test.com' -AddRole 'Contribute' -ClearExisting
```

The script runs on both occasions with no errors but the permission is only changed when -identity is the ID, am I missing something here?

[image]

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitempermission?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By list item object, it means passing the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem` object.

You are currently passing string which will not work.

You need to use `Get-PnPListItem` to get the list item and then pass it to the `Set-PnPListItemPermission` command.

To do that, you can use it as below:

```
$listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List 'Test' -Id 1
```

or passing CAML query, something like

```
$listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List 'Test' -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>TestFolder</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

And then

```
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Test' -Identity $listItem  -User 'Test@test.com' -AddRole 'Contribute' -ClearExisting
```

Reference - [Get-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#examples)

Comment: Thank you very much - I tried had tried $listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List 'Test' -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>TestFolder</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" | select ID at an earlier point in time but your answer was perfect